# shortcut to display long predefined string

Tags: asp.net, windows

is there a way in a text box (again web or windows app) that if you type a user-define sequence of characters it will automagically input a string of characters?

for instance, in my web or windows text box,
if i'm typing ABC it will enter replace the ABC with The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!

Comment: Of course there is.  But if you're wanting to know how to, you're going to have to make your question less broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly you can simply register with OnKeyUp event handler of the textbox.

```
private void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string newValue = ChangeUserDefinedSequence(((TextBox)sender).Text);

    ((TextBox)sender).Text = newValue;
}
```

and your function to handle the user-defined sequence could look something like this:

```
private string ChangeUserDefinedSequence(string txtBoxValue)
{
    if("ABC".Equals(txtBoxValue))
    {
        return "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog!";
    }

    return txtBoxValue;
}
```